# Why does Jenkins show TestCoverage multiple Times

Tags: jenkins, configuration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running an Jenkins Pipeline with serveral compilation and test stages. It also includes **4** jacoco evaluations of the kind

```
jacoco(execPattern: 'SubModule1/target/jacoco.exec', inclusionPattern: '**/*.class', classPattern: 'SubModule1/target/classes', sourcePattern: 'SubModule1/src/main/java', sourceInclusionPattern: '**/*.java')
```

It run's smoothly as expected, however the Job's page shows **7** entries for test coverage:

[image: Screenshot of Job Page (sorry it is in German]

How can I get rid of these extra entries?

Thank you for your kind support

Michael